# Ram is the man I thought to have killed/ have killed my brother

Tags: grammar, sentence-meaning, sentence-structure, grammaticality-in-context

> 1. Ram is the man I thought to have killed my brother.
> 2. Ram is the man I thought to kill my brother.
> 3. Ram is the man I thought have killed my brother.
> 4. Ram is the man I thought killed my brother.

Are theses sentences grammatically correct? Do they mean the same? Which one is more preferable? What's the meaning of each sentences. Please explain in detail. I'm so confused.

Comment: Has Ram already killed your brother?

Comment: Are you planning to get Ram to kill your brother?

Comment: Both (3)  and (4) would be better with **had killed**.

Comment: @HandyHowie my brother has been killed and I thought that Ram did that.

Comment: @KateBunting ok I get it. What about (1) and (2) ? Are they grammatical? Do they mean the same?

Comment: (1) is not idiomatic (though you could say **the man thought to have killed my brother** meaning that people in general thought so ('the man **who was** thought...). (2) suggests the interpretation that Michael gives.

Comment: Asking if something is correct is considered proofreading and off-topic here. Your question may be voted to be closed unless you can update it. Did you do some research? Can you include that research in your question? Is there a reason why you think what you've written might be wrong?

Comment: Asking what something means can usually be answered by a dictionary and is off-topic here. Your question may be voted to be closed unless you can update it. Did you do some research? Can you include that research in your question? Is there some conflicting definitions you found in your dictionary research that are confusing you?

Comment: If your brother reads (2), he will surely give Ram a wide berth henceforth.

Comment: @Astralbee - did you mean to ask this? _Is there some conflicting definitions you found in your dictionary research that are confusing you?_

Comment: **Oh please, Sahil. Couldn't you use another example? I find this odious**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 and 4 are grammatically correct and mean the same thing. 2 and 3 are not grammatically correct.

Normally a person would just say, "Ram is the man who killed my brother" or "Ram killed my brother". Adding some variant of "have" doesn't really change the meaning and just adds unnecessary words.

If you were planning to hire Ram to kill your brother at some time in the future, you could say, "Ram is the man I thought to have kill my brother."

Answer (score 0):

1. is grammatical, but rather formal or literary. It cannot be used with simple actions, but it can be used with descriptions, or the "state" of having done something, or doing something habitually:

So

> *She is thought to be highly intelligent.* (a description)

> *They were thought to want to go to America.* (a mental state)

> *He is thought to have killed somebody.* (a past infinitive - meaning "in the state of having done whatever it was")

> *He was thought to be running a smuggling operation.* (a continuous infinitive)

So your 2. could work if it didn't have a specific object:

> *This pesticide is thought to kill bees.*

but *thought to kill my brother* doesn't make sense, because the construction has to be habitual.

3. is not grammatical: *thought* in this way cannot be followed by the base form (or present form) of a verb: it must be the "to" infinitive.
4. is grammatical, but has a different structure: it is not *thought* + "to"-infinitive clause, it's *thought* + finite clause, withthe subject "raised" two levels:

> The man [(that) I thought [(that) (he) killed my brother]])

The first "that" is optional, but the second "that", and the "he" must be omitted.